# Prove equivalence $B⊆(C∪A) \iff (B\setminus A)⊆C$

Tags: real-analysis

Stuck on how to explain the answer for this one.

> If $A$, $B$, $C$ are non-empty then
>   $B⊆(C∪A) \iff (B\setminus A)⊆C$.

I know $B$ lays in $C$ entirely whereas $B$ does not lay in $A$. How can I explain this in a mathematical proof?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You do not know that $B$ lies entirely within $C$: this may not even be true.

You have two things to prove:

1. if $B\subseteq C\cup A$, then $B\setminus A\subseteq C$, and
2. if $B\setminus A\subseteq C$, then $B\subseteq C\cup A$.

I’ll prove the first of these implications as a model for you to try to follow in proving the second.

Suppose that $B\subseteq C\cup A$. Let $x\in B\setminus A$ be arbitrary; we want to show that $x\in C$. Suppose, to get a contradiction, that $x\notin C$. We know that $x\notin A$ (why?), so $x\notin C\cup A$, and therefore $x\notin B$. But $x\in B\setminus A$, so $x\in B$, and we have our contradiction. This shows that $x\in C$ and hence that $B\setminus A\subseteq C$.

Comment: @AVelj: Are you still confused about the part that I did, or are you just confused about how to do the second part?

Comment: @AVelj: Do you understand that one way to prove that a set $X$ is a subset of a set $Y$ is to show that if $x\in X$, then $x\in Y$? Because that, in outline, is what I’m doing, with $X=B\setminus A$ and $Y=C$.

Comment: I understand that, but its how you obtained contradiction that I'm still confused about. I'm re-reading what you have said but essentially: 

• Assume B⊆C∪A
• Let x∈B\A  (x is arbitrary) 
• To get a contradiction, assume x∉C
• Let x∉A
• x∉A=>x∉C∪A
• Therefore, x∉B since x∉C∪A 
• But x∈B\A so x∈B (this is our contradiction) 
• Therefore, x∈C and hence B\A⊆C 

That's my set up on my page

Comment: @AVelj: The contradiction is that $x\in B$ and $x\notin B$. That $x\in B$ follows from the fact that we started with an element $x$ of $B\setminus A$. That $x\notin B$ follows from $x\notin C\cup A$, since everything in $B$ is automatically in $C\cup A$. How did I get $x\notin C\cup A$? That just means that $x\notin C$ **and** $x\notin A$. I knew that $x\notin A$, because $x\in B\setminus A$, and I assumed that $x\notin C$ in order to get a contradiction. I was successful, so it’s not possible to have $x\notin C$. In other words, $x$ must be in $C$ after all, which is what I was trying for.

Comment: Yep I understand that. If I want to prove the converse is it also a contradiction? I think I know what to do now.

Comment: @AVelj: No, you won’t need contradiction for the second one. Just assume that $B\setminus A\subseteq C$, let $x\in B$, and try to show that $x\in C\cup A$. You’ll have to consider two cases: either $x\in B\setminus A$, or ...